# Reload collectionView when all data is ready

Tags: swift

I'm fetching some data from an endpoint, every time I requested for 10 items. These items contains a URL that should be scraping, which slow down the process a bit.

Due to some bug probably, the received data from scraping is not the same number of the original data, which something i will deal with later.  So I don't know when all data is ready.

Now, I want to make sure when I get all the data, then refresh the collection view. the only way that I can think of it, is using the timestamp of data and if the timestamp is not updated for about a sec, means, I have all the data that I need than I can refresh collection view. Not the best way of course

I added a timestamp variable

```
private lazy var fetchedTimestamp = Date().nanosecondsSince1970
```

then, whenever the data is recived I updated this timestamp with the the current time
Than, I use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` to check the timestamp on sec later and if the the timestamp one sec later is 1 sec after the last `fetchedTimestamp`update, means the data hasn't been updated for about a sec, so I know it's ready to reload

```
        KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: imageURL) { result in
            if let image = try? result.get().image {
                scraper.setBaseImage(with: image)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {  [weak self] in
                    guard let this = self else { return }
                    this.feedsCollectionView.feeds.append(scraper)
                    
                    this.fetchedTimestamp = Date().nanosecondsSince1970
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                        let currentTime = Date().nanosecondsSince1970
                        
                        if currentTime >= this.fetchedTimestamp + Int64(1e+9) {
                            this.feedsCollectionView.reload()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to handle it better? Thank you so much

Comment: Have you considered using a `DiffableDataSource` then you can update it whenever you get new data and reapply the snapshot to update the UI?  This will allow you to largely decouple the data acquisition and data display.

Comment: Yes actually, but I'm not so pro, and I checked it and it seems it only can be usable for a tableView like cell, mein is a bit more complex and its height size also need to be updated after tapping on it. are they possible in DiffableDataSource?

Comment: Also the cell should be in different size in the beginning based on their contents

Comment: It's for UICOllectionView too.  It drives the collection view itself, and is not directly related to the cell.  So you can use whatever cell you like. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource